# how can I prevent javascript from evaluating function parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript noob taking a crack at making minesweeper. I am passing HTML element ID strings to a function. The strings have the format row hyphen column. So the top left cell would be 1-1. My function is evaluating these strings as if they were expressions. So...

```
function notMine(id){
alert(id) //If the incoming id=4-4, this pops up 0. I want it to pop up 4-4
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to show us where `id` comes from. Your function does nothing wrong.

Comment: You cannot "fix" that; function parameters are expressions and are evaluated before the function is called. That's the way the language is defined.

Comment: That's not possible if you're passing in the string `"4-4"`.

Comment: Are you calling it like `notMine(4-4)` instead of `notMine("4-4")`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expressions are evaluated before the function is called, as they are not strings. Use apostrophes or quotation marks to make it a string:

```
notMine("4-4");
```

or

```
notMine('4-4');
```

Comment: Well technically the expression is still evaluated before the function is called :-)

Comment: @Pointy The pedantry police have been notified and are on their way! ;)

Comment: Questions like these bring out the worst in me, I admit.

Comment: I agree with Pointy, you have to return expression as string not integer type.

Comment: @wachpwnski That's not what Pointy is saying; Pointy is saying the string (the parameter) is evaluated before the function is called. It's a (correct) technicality.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass the parameter in, use quotes:

Cheers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    feedMe( 4 + 4 );
    feedMe( "4 + 4" );

    function feedMe( id )
    {
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```